# Converting PL/SQL trigger to T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, plsql

I am not good at T-SQL. How can does following trigger into T-SQL? For each doesn't work in T-SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DSS.TRG_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON DSS.CR_DEPO_STOK FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO CR_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME
            (ID_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME
           , ID_DEPO_STOK
           , MT_MIKTAR_ESKI
           , MT_MIKTAR_YENI
           , EKLEME_TARIHI
            )
     VALUES (SEQ_ID_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME.NEXTVAL
           , :NEW.ID_DEPO_STOK
           , :OLD.MT_MIKTAR
           , :NEW.MT_MIKTAR
           , SYSDATE
            );

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

Comment: There are no sequences in TSQL until next version. Are you using an identity column instead? Also what does ` WHEN OTHERS` do?

Comment: Yes,i am using identity column.Others arent important,needless to convert

Comment: @MartinSmith:  WHEN OTHERS is a catch all for all unhandled exceptions in PL\SQL.  It is best used to rethrow errors that you didn't code for.  Using it "naked" as above essentially hides all untrapped exceptions.  There's a long rant about it at:  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1270688200346183091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER DSS.TRG_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME
   ON DSS.CR_DEPO_STOK
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS   
BEGIN

INSERT INTO CR_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME
            (ID_DEPO_STOK
           , MT_MIKTAR_ESKI
           , MT_MIKTAR_YENI
           , EKLEME_TARIHI
            )
SELECT       i.ID_DEPO_STOK
           , d.MT_MIKTAR
           , i.MT_MIKTAR
           , GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED i FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED d ON i.pk = d.pk            

END;
```

There are no row triggers in TSQL also sequences will not appear until the next version so I have assumed that `ID_DEPO_STOK_IZLEME` will be an `identity` column.

Comment: martin,thanks for ur answer.But it raises Invalid column name 'pk'. error.